# Checking multiple conditions for a string in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to check multiple conditions in a string in C# but it throws error saying Cannot use && for string or boolean

```
if ((duStart.Trim() != "" && duStart.Trim() != null) &&(duEnd.Trim() != "" && duEnd.Trim() != null))
{
//do this
}
else
//do that
```

Comment: `Trim()` cannot return `null`.  Look at the `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method.

Comment: The code you have posted compiles. The error is somewhere else. Please post the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've given compiles fine. Here's a short but complete program - I've changed the whitespace of your line of code, but that's all:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string duStart = "X";
        string duEnd = "X";
        if ((duStart.Trim() != "" && duStart.Trim() != null) &&
            (duEnd.Trim() != "" && duEnd.Trim() != null))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Having said that:

- If you're going to use the same value (the trimmed version of `duStart`, for example) multiple times, there seems little point in computing it twice. I'd have used extra local variables (`trimmedStart`, `trimmedEnd`) here
- [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) *never* returns null, so those tests are pointless.
- Using [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) is probably a better idea here. Why bother creating strings that you're never going to use?

Comment: Btw the strange null check could mean that the originals duStart and duEnd *could* be null, if this is the case a check has to be done before

Comment: @Felice: Nope, because then calling `duStart.Trim()` would throw an exception to start with, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify the condition by writing:

```
if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(duStart.Trim()) && !string.isNullOrEmpty(duEnd.Trim()) )
{
}
```

Comment: Better to use the suggestion of SLaks, IsNullOrWhiteSpace, and avoid using Trim at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Null first for duStart and duEnd. Then try Trim the string. Trim cannot be applied on a null value. So, below code block should work for you.

```
if ((duStart != null && duStart.Trim() != "") && (duEnd != null && duEnd.Trim() != ""))
{ 
   //do this 
}
else
{
   //do that 
}
```